# What does the "%" mean in tcl?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, tcl

In a situation like this for example:

```
[% $create_port %]

or [list [% $RTL_LIST %]]
```

I realized it had to do with the brackets, but what confuses me is that sometimes it is used with the brackets and variable followed, and sometimes you have brackets with variables inside without the `%`.

So i'm not sure what it is used for.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a working code snippet with this?
% is the standard/default TCL prompt. That's the only usage I'm familiar with, in TCL.

Comment: After [, the interpreter expects a command. In Tcl you may name commands (or procs) just about anything you want, including %. But % isn't a command that is defined out of the box. So it seems that has been created somewhere in your application.

Comment: % is actually defined as a command in the tcl::mathop. It calculates the integral modules of its arguments. So % would be a valid command if you did a `namespace import tcl::mathop::*`, but your examples don't fit the expected arguments for that command.

Comment: Looks more like some template directive (start and end tags). The OP will have to tell more about her setup, I am afraid.

Comment: Thanks all for the help. I will try to ask the person who wrote the actual code. It might be just as you guys said, something that is just there for individual reference.

Answer (score 0):

`%` is not a metacharacter in the Tcl language core, but it still has a few meanings in Tcl. In particular, it's the modulus operator in `expr` and a substitution field specifier in `format`, `scan`, `clock format` and `clock scan`. (It's also the default prompt character, and I have a trivial pass-through `%` command in my `~/.tclshrc` to make cut-n-pasting code easier, but nobody else in the world needs to follow my lead there!)

But the code you have written does not appear to be any of those (because it would be a syntax error in all of the commands I've mentioned). It looks like it is some sort of directive processing scheme (with the special sequences being `[%` and `%]`, *with* the brackets) though not one I recognise such as [doctools](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/doctools/doctools_lang_intro.html) or [rivet](https://tcl.apache.org/rivet/). Because a program that embeds a Tcl interpreter could do an arbitrary transformation to scripts before executing them, it's extremely difficult to guess what it might really be.